# Polymer selected value of core-menu by name

Tags: javascript, menu, polymer

For navigation on my website I'd like to be able to select an item from the [`core-menu`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-menu) in [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org). Here's some sample code I have made for testing: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nijezebe/1/edit).

You can see in the example that I am able to retrieve the label-value of the selected item using `this.selectedMenu.label`, with `selectedMenu` being bound to the `selectedItem={{selectedMenu}}` of th core-menu.

I also demonstrate that it is possible to use the numeric value to change the state, using `this.$.mainMenu.selected = x`, `x` being a numeric value starting from 0.

Now I was wondering whether it is possible to update the selected value with the label name instead of numeric value.

Here's the code again:

```
    <polymer-element name='my-app' noscript>
      <template>
        <style>
          paper-item.core-selected {
            color: #99182c;
            fill: #99182c;
          }
        </style>
        <core-menu selected="0" selectedItem="{{selectedMenu}}" id="mainMenu" on-core-select="{{mainMenu}}">
          <paper-item icon="home" label="Home"></paper-item>
          <paper-item icon="today" label="Activities"></paper-item>
          <paper-item icon="account-box" label="People"></paper-item>
          <paper-item icon="theaters" label="Pictures"></paper-item>
          <paper-item icon="info" label="Info"></paper-item>
          <paper-item icon="lock" label="Login"></paper-item>  
        </core-menu>
        This is the selected item: {{selectedMenu.label}}.<br>
        <div on-tap="{{forceStateHome}}">Force state home</div>
      </template>
      <script>
        Polymer("my-app", {
          mainMenu: function(){
            console.log("New item selected: " + this.selectedMenu.label);
          },
          forceStateHome: function(){
            console.log("Forcing state to home...");
            this.$.mainMenu.selected = 0; //I want to use a name, not number
          }
        });
      </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*core-menu* can use any attribute of the child elements for its *selected* value by setting the *valueattr* attribute ([core-selector documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-selector)).

I suggest to give each *paper-item* an id (say `id='home'`) and set *valueattr* to `valueattr='id'`.

Then you can write `this.$.mainMenu.selected = 'home'`.